# Can't enable Windows time service (Windows 10) - Access is denied even to Administrator

Tags: windows

My W10 computer is unable to sync time (sync failed).  I found that the time service is not running.

When I try to start it, I get `"Access is denied"` - even in an **Administrator** shell:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start w32time
System error 5 has occurred.
Access is denied.
```

There are many help articles on this, but the first thing they always say to do is:

```
w32tm /unregister
```

Which also results in 'Access is denied (0x80070005)'.

For that matter 'w32tm /register' generates the same
error too.

So any answer that says to stop the time service, unregister it, and register it again will not work as access is denied for those operations also.

How do I get the time service running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Time not synchronizing - "Access is denied" error](https://superuser.com/questions/1200156/windows-time-not-synchronizing-access-is-denied-error) and/or [Windows 10 unable to time sync, time service is greyed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1530760/windows-10-unable-to-time-sync-time-service-is-greyed-out)

Comment: @jluizsouzadev - The author specifically indicated they are indeed an Administrator and/or have the ability to launch a command prompt as an Administrator.  It doesn't matter what their account name is.  There already is a known solution, to the issue described, in an existing answer.

Comment: Have you also ruled out group policy?  (Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment) "change the system time, change the time zone" should both be LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators

Comment: @Bob - Try the accepted answer to the second duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Ramhound's reference #2: [Windows 10 unable to time sync, time service is greyed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1530760/windows-10-unable-to-time-sync-time-service-is-greyed-out) describes the situation here exactly.  Even the behavior described in that issue under "EDIT1" and "EDIT2" is identical.

The solution was to do the in-place update given in the answer: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case 99% of the solutions found on the web failed because Group Policies had been tinkered with.

Try this:

Start the Local Group Policy Editor (run as administrator)
Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Windows Time Service > Time Providers

Enable the following:

- Configure Windows NTP Client: Enabled (policy settings are described below);
- Enable Windows NTP Client: Enabled;
- Enable Windows NTP Server: Enabled.

Then open a CMD.EXE window as administrator and start the w32time service